# Array animation in ReactJS, TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, animation

I'm making a sliding tree navigation component in React.
When going forward the new list slides in from the right, the old one slides out to the left.
I do it with `<TransitionGroup>` and `<CSSTransition>`. 
I am removing the old list from the array and adding the new one to it, every item is properly keyed. It works.
However when going back it doesn't.

**I have a demo here:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/1wq71p5ly3

When navigating back, in `<App>` component state I am flipping a boolean value and supply it to `<TreeContainer>` component so inside `<CSSTransition>` a different CSS class could be applied (basically reversing the direction of the `translate`).

When removing and adding from an array (and then setting state)  for some reason the `<TreeContainer>` is called 3 times (I guess one for removal, one for addition and one for... I don't know). This is still fine when navigating forward, but when I go backward as you can see in the demo, I logged the boolean value inside `<TreeContainer>` after explicitly setting its value inside the parent with `setState` and this is what I got:

```
false
true
false
```

It is still called three times, but once the boolean value is `true`, even though I set it explicitly to `false`.

I have no clue why does it work in one direction and why doesn't in the other.
It must be some minor thing I am overlooking, but I can't see it.
I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<TreeContainer>` is called 3 times because: it's called for each new item and for each item that will be removed.

When you go `Back` new state is never passed to `<TreeContainer>`, but CSS Transition excutes it anyway with old `forward` prop.

To change it you need to have two step state transition. I recommend using setState callback like this:

```
  navForward(branch: INavTreeElement) {

    var fullTreeUI = this.state.treeUI.slice();
    var filteredDataTree = findById(this.props.NavDataTree, branch.id);
    var nextTreeUI: any = {
      branch: filteredDataTree.children.map((i: any) => { return { name: i.name, id: i.id }; }),
      id: Math.random().toString(36).substring(2)
      + (new Date()).getTime().toString(36)
    };

    treeStack.push(this.state.treeUI.slice()[0]);
    fullTreeUI.push(nextTreeUI);
    fullTreeUI.shift();

    this.setState({
      forward: true,
    }, () => {
      this.setState({
        treeUI: fullTreeUI,
        depth: (this.state.depth + 1)
      });
    });
  }

  navBackward() {

    var fullTreeUI: any = this.state.treeUI.slice();
    fullTreeUI.unshift(treeStack.pop());
    fullTreeUI.pop();

    this.setState({
      forward: false,
    }, () => {
      this.setState({
        treeUI: fullTreeUI,
        depth: (this.state.depth - 1)
      });
    });
  }
```

This fixes your issue. Cheers

Comment: Thanks, it works flawlessly. 
What do you mean by _When you go Back new state is never passed to <TreeContainer>_ ? When I click the back button I set the state of `<App>` and `<TreeContainer>` receives it as a prop (the forward boolean).
Or this callback thing is due to some asynchronicity nature of `setState`?

Comment: The problem is that when you change at the same time state properties `forward` and `treeUI` - the old value of `treeUI` (the one that's going to disappear) never gets the new forward property. In your render method you have: `{this.state.treeUI}` when you change at the same time `{this.state.treeUI}`and `{this.state.forward}` the component that will be unmount will never know that direction is going to change.

Comment: See this https://codesandbox.io/s/k10wqy4y9o I've added additional console.log in TreeContainer. Maybe it will show you what's the problem.
EDIT:

And yes, because setState is asynchronious it goes like that:
set new state of forward => tell currently mounted `TreeContainer` that direction has changed (new value for `forward` property is passed`) => set new state of treeUI to display new navigation item.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it. 
But now the `<App>` component renders twice (for each `setState`). Do you know how to avoid this? Or it's not that big of a deal?

Comment: Actually it is required for this solution to work. First render change `TreeContainer` direction (so it will be animated properly), second render change navigation items, but do not worry it's not a big deal. React has it's virtual DOM and knows what need update.